# Can Entity Framework Core run SqlQuery?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this code in .Net Framework. There is nothing wrong with it.

```
    // no problem in .net core
    public bool ExecuteQuery(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, parameters) > 0;
    }
```

not found (`SqlQuery`) in Entity Framework Core

```
    public List<T> SqlQuery(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, parameters).ToList();
        return result;
    }

    public object ExecuteNonQuery(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query, parameters);
        return result;
    }
```

How can I write the same code in .net core 2.1 ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types

Answer (score -1):

You can't execute SqlQuery in EF Core, it requires to define a POCO class and a  `DbSet` for that class. Then you can use it like:

```
using (var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var books = context.Books.FromSql("SELECT * FROM Books").ToList();
}
```

Comment: This isn't the whole story any more.

Comment: @GertArnold: Care to elaborate?

Comment: There's `Database.ExecuteSqlRaw` now.